# Why doesn't my variable work in my SELECT statement

Tags: php

```
session_start();
$username = $_SESSION['username'];

$db = new PDO("mysql:host=".DBHOST.";charset=utf8mb4;dbname=".DBNAME, 
DBUSER, DBPASS);

function keygrabber($username) { //You need to pass a variable into this 
function
global $db; //Gain access to the $db variable, which is out of scope due to 
being inside of a function
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM keys WHERE username='$username'"); 
//Prepare the query
$stmt->execute(); //Execute the query
$results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); //Fetch the query results
var_dump($results); //Dump the results
}

keygrabber($username);
```

So If I change `username='$username';` to `username='myactualusername';`, it works, i.e. it shows no errors or anything.

I'm basically trying to get all data out of keys that matches the user's username. I'll change this to userID In the future but now variables are not working so I am unable to progress.

Thanks for the help

Comment: Have you checked what `$username` actually contains?

Comment: Can you try with the $GLOBALS['db'] instead of $db

Comment: Hey, I see you are using pdo. Please use prepared statements!

Comment: Does `keygrabber('myactualusername');` work?

Comment: @RamanKumar, it would be better to pass it in as a parameter than use any form of global.

Comment: Check your session, are you getting data in $username variable?

Comment: @NigelRen yup, are you right :)

Comment: using `global` keyword is bad practice.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try like this

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM keys WHERE username='$username'");
```

Hope it will make sense..

Comment: Strings should be enclosed in `''` in MySQL

Comment: this is way off as `$_SESSION['username'];` is obviously empty

Comment: @uttam_devani I agreed with kerbholz

Answer (score 1):

You should not use php var in SQL (you are at risk for sqlinjection) you should use prepared statementes and param binding

be sure that your $username contain a valid value  firts and then

```
   $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM keys WHERE username=:username"); 
   $stmt->bindParam(':username', $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
   $stmt->execute();
```

Comment: Apart from the comment about making sure you actually have a value in `$username` how does this solve OP's problem?

Answer (score 0):

try this 
 
prepare("SELECT * FROM keys WHERE username=?"); 
$stmt->execute([$username]);

$rows = $stmt->fetchAll();